# SFML Vector for Class Initializing

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I want to initialize my Obstacle Class with a SF Vector.
Means the Class looks like this:

```
Obstacle(Vector2f ObstaclePosition)
```

and my question is, what should the source file look like? I tried things like:

```
Obstacle Obst1(300, 200)
```

but that obviously didn't worked.

Anyone with a Idea? Thank's in advantage.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Obstacle Obst1(Vector2f(300.0f, 200.0f))`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Vector2.php) of the `sf::Vector2<T>` class, there are three constructors available:

```
Vector2(); // empty

Vector2(T X, T Y); // two parameters

template <typename U>
explicit Vector2(const Vector2<U>& vector); // from another Vector object
```

So you can use the second constructor, like this:

```
Obstacle Obst1(Vector2f(300, 200));
```

or

```
const Vector2f v(300, 200);
Obstacle Obst1(v);
```

The compiler should be able to accept an `initializer_list`, so you could also do this:

```
Obstacle Obst1({300, 200});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Obstacle Obst1(Vector2f(300, 200))
```

And I'm not sure, but this may work too:

```
Obstacle Obst1({300, 200})
```

The difference between your line and those lines is that in your line you try to use `Obstacle(float, float)` constructor (which is probably isn't exist), and in those lines I'm using `Obstacle(Vector2f)` constructor.

Comment: Oh easier than I thought, thank you so much! Both ways work and yeah thanks for the explanation :)